# How to organize and run unittests and functional tests separately using nosetests

Tags: python, unit-testing, functional-testing, nose, nosetests

I have the following typical python project file structure

```
packageA
   +----subpackage1
            +----classa.py
   +----subpackage2
            +----classb.py
   +----test
          +----subpackage1
                    +----classa_test.py 
          +----subpackage2
                    +----classb_test.py
```

I am currently trying to organize my unittests and functional tests so I can run unittests and functional tests separately using nose but also have the option to run all tests. The tests would live in packageA/test/subpackage1 and packageA/test/subpackage2.

- What is a good way to organize the different tests? By folder (functional/ vs unit/) ? By naming convention of test class (ClassATest vs ClassAFunctionalTest)? or by naming convention of test methods (classa_foo_test vs classa_bar_functional_test)?
- Can someone explain how nosetests's regex matching works? The options -m, -i and -e don't seem to run as I expect to run. Does the regex match directories (subpackage1), files (classa_test) or test classes (ClassATest) or test methods (classa_foo_test)? I am extremely confused

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My tests directory structure looks this way:

```
root
  + --- tests
  |       + --- unit_tests
  |       |         + --- some_app_tests   
  |       |         + --- another_app_tests
  |       |         | run_tests.py
  |       |
  |       + --- integrate_tests 
  |                 + --- some_app_tests
  |                 + --- another_app_tests
  |                 | run_tests.py
  |       
  + --- project_root
          + --- some_app
          + --- another_app
```

For each individual app I create coresponding directory with tests in unit- and integrate- directory. Each is directory is separate django project with custom settings and there's management command used to run tests.

Also placing tests in one directory has one nice advantage - when project is deployed, there's no reason to deploy tests with it. So I just strip one directory and that's all.

(to run tests I use django-sane-testing: https://github.com/Almad/django-sane-testing )

Comment: You say "Each is directory is separate django project with custom settings and there's management command used to run tests" but your tree doesn't actually show this. Also, what's the custom management command you're using?

Comment: @supervacuo I did not say **custom managegement command**, but management command with **custom settings**. Tests are runned by django-sane-testing via `manage.py test` command (with some modifications in settings, wrapped into `run_tests.py`, see DST doc -  http://django-sane-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#running-tests )

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing Django project, you can try this library: unclebob https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/unclebob

It suggest a way how to organize and run your unit tests and functional tests.

Comment: +1 I hadn't seen `unclebob` before, but it seems a really nice way to encourage good test practices (I particularly like "if you run only the unit tests, then unclebob is NOT going to setup the test database"), and it's even pretty recently updated.

Answer (score -2):

I would try to organize the test by functional area. I don't really know what nose is.

But if you for example testing a login area for a webpage then create a subfolder called "login" or "loginTests", and for menu test create a "menu" or "menuTests" folder. It is always good to have good naming conventions as well, so name the test and folders exactly what they are testing. Be as specific as you can be.