# Running unit and integration tests (residing in different directories) separately using nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, nose

I was wondering this already for a while now, but I was not able to figure out how to pass options to `nosetests` to run different tests which reside in different sub-directories. Example of an package directory structure:

```
my_package/
|-- my_module1/
   |-- tests/
       |-- unit/
           | ... a bunch of unit tests
       |-- integration/
           |... a bunch of integration tests
|-- my_module2/
   |-- tests/
       |-- unit/
           | ... a bunch of unit tests
       |-- integration/
           |... a bunch of integration tests
```

If I want to execute just the unit tests in all my modules (all the tests in `tests/unit/` sub-directories), how would I do that using the nosetests library?

Answer (score 2):

I think `--where` or `--match` nosetests arguments can help you:

> -w WHERE, --where=WHERE
>                           Look for tests in this directory. May be specified
>                           multiple times. The first directory passed will be
>                           used as the working directory, in place of the current
>                           working directory, which is the default. Others will
>                           be added to the list of tests to execute. [NOSE_WHERE]
>
> -m REGEX, --match=REGEX, --testmatch=REGEX
>                           Files, directories, function names, and class names
>                           that match this regular expression are considered
>                           tests.  Default: (?:^|[\b_./-])[Tt]est
>                           [NOSE_TESTMATCH]

Also, see [Anyone know how nosetest's -m, -i and -e work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054512/anyone-know-how-nosetests-m-i-and-e-work)

But, actually, I prefer to have tests dir at the root level: [How to organize and run unittests and functional tests separately using nosetests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043417/how-to-organize-and-run-unittests-and-functional-tests-separately-using-nosetest?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, the point is that I don't want to specify each directory one by one when passing the `-w` option (assuming I have a huge project). I looked into `-m` as well, but couldn't figure it out so far. I guess I have to dig a little deeper.